# Specified file failed upload test. wp_upload_handle

Tags: php, uploads

So I managed to write a peice of code that allows me to upload a zip file, im not even sure where it gets uploaded too, and I am doing it on my localhost with apache in control (www-data). the code is as follows:

```
public function upload_file(array $file){
    add_filter('upload_mimes', array($this, accepted_mime_type));

    if(wp_handle_upload($file, array('test_form' => false))){
        var_dump(wp_handle_upload($file, array('test_form' => false)));
    }else{
        $this->error('Oops!', 'Something went wrong with the upload. Please try again.');
    }       
}
```

the error I get is: Specified file failed upload test

Im not sure whats going on, this is localhost.

Comment: What is going on is that you are calling wp_handle_upload() twice and the second time is failing.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is coming from [`wp_handle_upload()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_handle_upload/):

```
// A properly uploaded file will pass this test. There should be no reason to override this one.
if ( $test_upload && ! @ is_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'] ) )
    return call_user_func($upload_error_handler, $file, __( 'Specified file failed upload test.' ));
```

I am not sure about your context, but what you are trying to do seems to not be POST upload and as such fails [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) check.

Comment: What do you mean its not a POST? how else would you call this function other then hitting submit on a form containing a file? this error does not seem clear, please explain further, and or show what you would write to make it pass. I did a var dump on `is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])` and I got a bool true, which means that is was uploaded via HTTP POST. Turns out the second option should be 'false', as it was $test_form that was freaking out

Comment: Hm, actually it seems to be checking for `!` so not POST upload... Sorry, as much sense as I could make of it from quick look (not my area).