# Validate Uploaded Image using WordPress' Built-in Functions?

Tags: php, images, uploads, validation

I have a form that allows users to upload an image. I'm using the code below (which currently doesn't work) to ensure what a user uploads is valid.

Can someone help me out and either update my code or point me in the right direction as to how I can use as many of the built-in WordPress functions (wp_check_filetype_and_ext()), or anything else that would be well-suited,  to handle the validation as possible? It also must be secure to prevent any malicious files, attacks, etc.

```
if ( $_FILES ) {
  foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    //Check if the $_FILES is set and if the size is > 0 (if =0 it's empty)
    if ( isset( $_FILES[$file]) && ($_FILES[$file]['size'] > 0 ) ) {
      $tmpName = $_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'];
      list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = @getimagesize($tmpName);

      if ($width != 500 || $height != 500) {
        $error .= "Image is to small<br />";
        unlink($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
      }

      // Get the type of the uploaded file. This is returned as "type/extension"
      $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES[$file]['name']));
      $uploaded_file_type = $arr_file_type['type'];

      // Set an array containing a list of acceptable formats
      $allowed_file_types = array('image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png');

      // If the uploaded file is the right format
      if (in_array($uploaded_file_type, $allowed_file_types)) {
      } else { // wrong file type
        $error .= "Please upload a JPG, GIF, or PNG file<br />";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Have you considered using `media_handle_upload` instead?](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not really familiar with it, nor am I a PHP developer. The only part I need is file validation. I have functionality in place to handle the image uploading, saving, etc. What do you recommend?

Comment: I'd recommend using the WordPress APIs for as much of it as possible. That way your using tried and tested code, maintained by people whose job it is to make it work

Comment: The image is uploaded using BuddyPress, along with the BuddyPress XProfile Image Field plug-in. It just doesn't have any validation so users can upload whatever they want!

Answer (score 3):

All of the code in your question can be replaced with:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
if ( $_FILES ) {
  foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $image_post_id = media_handler_upload( $file );
    if ( is_wp_error( $image_post_id ) ) {
      $error .= $image_post_id->get_error_message();
    } else {
      // $image_post_id now holds the post ID of an attachment that is your uploaded file
    }
  }
}
```

The power of [`media_handle_upload`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) means that now you have now completely outsourced your security, checking, and uploading to WordPress Core. `media_handle_upload` will be maintained long after you've finished your project, by people who are far smarter than either of us, and other people with a vested interest in keeping WordPress secure.

`media_handle_upload` will do all of the checking you get when you upload things via the dashboard, and will create attachment posts to represent these uploaded files in the database. It will also handle the creation of different image sizes, and compatibility with plugins, and respect the security settings specified in the dashboard.

If successful, it will return the ID of the attachment post it created. If unsuccessful, it will return a `WP_Error` object with an error message.

You can then use [`wp_get_attachment_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) if you need the full URL of the attachment, or [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) if you need to get a particular size for the image, e.g.:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_post_id, 'thumbnail' );
if ( $image != false ) {
    echo $image[0];
}
```

Comment: The form is actually located on the front-end. Would this solution still work there as well? All I really need it to do is just flag an error if it's: an invalid file, not the exact dimensions, and over a specified file size. If it passes all these requirements, then the functionality is in place to handle the image (uploading, store the info in the database, etc.)

Comment: This code is for the handling of the form once it's submitted, and it will give you an attachment post. What you do with that attachment post is up to you, without knowing anything more about how the values are stored or what you then do with them, I can't comment. However, checking the size, file type, etc, is all handled by `media_handle_upload`. What I have in my answer should function in place of what you posted in your question

Comment: I'm getting `Warning: Missing argument 2 for media_handle_upload()...` Any ideas how to get it to work without a `$post_id`? A post ID doesn't exist for the page that contains the form.

Comment: Ah yes, you can pass a 0 according to the documentation if you don't want to attach it to anything

Comment: I added includes to media.php and async-upload.php, but it's prompting me to log into the WP Admin. This has to work on the front-end for logged in users. Is there anyway to get media_handle_upload to work there and not in the WP Admin?

Comment: You shouldn't need to include `async-upload.php`, that file isn't a header/library, it's a User Interface admin screen, I've added the require statements to the answer

Comment: I hate to keep bugging you, but not sure what to do. I updated my code to include the require statements, but I keep getting "Specified file failed upload test." for a valid PNG.

Comment: possibly related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101050/specified-file-failed-upload-test-wp-upload-handle can you put the frontend upload form in your question?